# how to stop a program running in the server?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I m doing a eclipse plugin project to create an IDE for a particular language.
For running i connect to the server and ask the user the command,type of connection...

After the program has started execution The only way to stop the execution of the program is by pressing "ctrl+C" when done in the command prompt.
I run the program by sending the server the following command:
 "probevue filename.e >output.txt"

when i give this command it is running,but i m not able to stop the program...
i.e when i press Ctrl+C the program should stop execution.

How shall i do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Common eclipse server plugins like [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools) call the server scripts that are delivered with the server for starting and stopping. Deployment/undeployment and starting/stopping of applications is done via the management port.

So either you have a manageable server to control your program, or you could work around the problem by writing the scripts yourself.

Comment: JBoss Tools is an extension of Eclipse you can check out here: http://www.jboss.org/tools

Answer (score 0):

after reading into this article about probevue it seems that you have started a dynamic session. i think the program you're calling is never terminating itself.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds4%2Fprobevue.htm

you should first read how to invoke a command properly. e.g. -> http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t53333.html

then you should think about how would you terminate the command if you wouldn't have the ctrl+c option, like finding out the process-id of the shell command you executed before (e.g.: ps -ef | grep ) and terminating it by using another shell command (e.g.: kill -9 )

hope this helps you find a solution.